# How to compare multiple array get result only same time in each array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to compare multiple array get array result only same time in each array with javascript?  consider performance

```
var a = [10],
    b = [],
    c = [10],
    d = [10];

get []

var a = [10],
    b = [10],
    c = [10],
    d = [10];

get [10]

var a = [0, 1, 2],
    b = [1, 2],
    c = [0, 1, 2],
    d = [0, 1, 2, 3];

get [1, 2]
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1885557/218196) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+intersection+arrays).

Comment: Could someone fix that first sentence? I'm not sure what it means, but it's definitely not correct English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution features a nondestructive algorithm for getting the intersection for two arrays (`intersection`) and a group of arrays (`intersections`).

```js
function intersection(a, b) {
    var array = [];
    a.forEach(function (aa) {
        b.some(function (bb) {
            if (aa === bb) {
                array.push(aa);
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    return array;
}

function intersections(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return intersection(a, b);
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(intersections([[10], [], [10], [10]]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(intersections([[10], [10], [10], [10]]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(intersections([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

[_.intersection](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection) is one way :)

```
_.intersection([1, 2], [4, 2], [2, 1]);
// → [2]
```

See [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). This is useful if the purpose of your question is more for utility rather than academic reasons. No need to reinvent the wheel, unless it's just for learning purposes.